# Dynamically Create Variables C++/cli .NET

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I am importing a text file in C++ /cli with:

```
array<System::String^>^ Filelines = IO::File::ReadAllLines(path);
```

The next step is to use the String::Split on each element of the array, but the issue is, i do not know how long the array will be. Is there a way to create a particular number of `array<System::String^>^` depending on the number of elements in my first array `Filelines`.

Ideally it would look like this:

```
array<System::String^>^ Filelines = IO::File::ReadAllLines(path);
array<System::String^>^ row1 = Filelines[0]->Split(',');
array<System::String^>^ row2 = Filelines[1]->Split(',');
...
array<System::String^>^ rown= Filelines[n]->Split(',');
```

What are my options? Can I make an array of arrays?

Comment: Use a `List<string>^`

Comment: @asawyer: The type `List<std::string>^` can't exist, mixing managed and unmanaged types like that isn't possible.  You could do `List<System::String^>^` or `std::vector<std::string>` or even `List<std::string*>^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use an array of arrays:

```
array<System::String^>^ Filelines = IO::File::ReadAllLines(path);
array<array<System::String^>^> ^test = gcnew array<array<System::String^>^>(Filelines->Length);
test[0] = Filelines[0]->Split(',');
test[1] = Filelines[1]->Split(',');
```